# Native control converted to WPF not capturing tab key

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a native control that has been brought over to WPF. It has been placed inside a Frame control for it to work correctly. The issue I'm having is that Tabbing through controls in my window treats the "frame" as a single control, and not the control that is inside this control. WPF then tabs through the rest of the controls I have in my window (buttons, menu etc).

How can I get the control inside the Frame to capture the tab key and then tab through its own controls? The control does have textboxes, and I can type inside it; it seems to only be the tab key so far.

The Tab key works fine in WinForms so I'm only assuming it's WPF/Frame that's causing the issue, and not the WPF-port itself.